# Proving convergence of a sequence with a given property

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, proof-verification, proof-writing

Let $$a_{n + 1} = \begin{cases} a_{n} + 1/n &  \text{ if }  a_{n}^{2} \leq 2 \\
a_{n} - 1/n & \text{ if } a_{n}^{2} > 2
\end{cases}$$

Show that for every index $n$, $\left|a_{n} - \sqrt{2}\right| < 2/n$, and use this property to show that the sequence converges to $\sqrt{2}$.

So, I did the first part of this problem by proving by induction. The base case is obvious, and then for the induction step I just split it into two cases, one for each condition. But, now I'm having trouble using this sequence converges to $\sqrt{2}$ using the property that I established.

I'm pretty sure that I need to do an $\epsilon-N$ verification, since this is a real analysis book, in the convergence section. I'm really not sure how I would go about it, though.

Comment: Can you show $\frac{2}{n} \to 0$ using $\varepsilon$-$N$? Exactly the same $N$ will work for $a_n \to \sqrt{2}$, using the first part of the question.

Comment: Okay, I have proved that $2/n \rightarrow 0$, but I'm not sure how the result follows.

Comment: Well, you have $n \ge N \implies \frac{2}{n} < \varepsilon$, right? Well then, using the same $N$ for the given $\varepsilon$, we also have $$n \ge N \implies |a_n - \sqrt{2}| < \frac{2}{n} < \varepsilon,$$ using part (a). So, in total, you've found an $N$ such that $n \ge N \implies |a_n - \sqrt{2}| < \varepsilon$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $2/n\to 0$ when $n\to\infty$.

> For $\epsilon>0$, choose $n_0\in\mathbb N$ such that $2/n_0<\epsilon$. Then we have, for $n>n_0$,
>  $$|a_n-\sqrt{2}|\le 2/n < 2/n_0 < \epsilon$$